# In Sub-Fragment , When webview can not go back then how to redirect to Main-Fragment or Home-Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**In my app I had create a Main Fragment with 2 Buttons, each Button has different fragment with different webview. This is my Sub-Fragment's Code, I am new here so forgive me for my mistakes.**

```
public class SubFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView webView;


    public SubFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub, container, false);

        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

**Here is code of goBack. I just want to redirect on Main Fragmnet when webview can not goBack**

```
       webView.canGoBack();
       webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

   return view;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if would go back to main fragment, you need to use ChildFragmentManager in MainFragment as code below :

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
manager.popBackStack();
```